# Spring Boot is not loading the properties from a YML file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito

My test file is :

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class MyApplicationTest {
    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    protected MyController myController;

}
```

My `Controller` file is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="${app.base-path}")  // Unable to load this property
public class MyController {

}
```

I have tried `@TestPropertySource` but did not work. 
The `SpringBootApplication` works fine.
This is not the case with `@Value` annotation.
Fields decorated with `@Value` annotation works just fine.

Comment: paste the application.yml

Comment: Maybe this property you depend on is not avaiable to the "dev" profile in your YML?

Comment: If you are trying to add a base path for every endpoint of your application, you can configure it with `spring.contextPath: context-path-here`

Comment: Refer to the Spring YML working example Spring Boot Profiles YAML Properties example

Comment: Is `app.base-path` defined in application.properties or in another .porperties file?

Answer (score 2):

Did you name your .yml file as `application.yml` and put it on the `src/main/resources` or `src/test/resources`?

Placing the application.yml file on those folders will automatically add it to the classpath so you can access this file properties at runtime.

Comment: Is it resources folder under 'src/main/' or 'src/test'?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Spring Boot will try to load `application.yml` **and** `application-{profilename}.yml` available on classpath, so you could try with `application-test.yml` (it will eliminate the problem with defining profiles in one file - maybe it causes your problem).

Also, you could try with `bootstrap.yml`, which is loaded before `application.yml`.